# Busqueda en archivo json dentro de un array flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

tengo una duda, estoy realizando una aplicación pero tengo que en el archivo json dentro de una key tengo almacenado el typo del pokemon en una lista puesto que tiene varios tipos y cuando genero una busqueda, no me detecta todas las palabras de la lista que esta dentro si no solo la primera.
type es la lista, ya esta transformada de dinamica a string solo no se como hacer la busqueda puesto dependiendo el pokemon es como cambia el numero de elemento de esa key

```
pokeHub.pokemon.where((poke) =>poke.type[0].toLowerCase().contains(_searchtype().toLowerCase()))
```

EL json o ejemplo de algunos datos

```
"pokemon": [
  {
    "id": 722,
    "num": "722",
    "name": "Rowlet",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/722.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass","Flying"
    ],
    "height": "0.3 m",
    "weight": "1.5 kg",
    "candy": "None",
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0,
    "avg_spawns": 0,
    "spawn_time": "N/A",
    "multipliers": null,
    "weaknesses": [
        "Fire",
        "Flying",
        "Ice",
        "Poison",
        "Rock"
    ],
    "next_evolution": [{
      "num": "723",
      "name": "Dartrix"
    },
    {
      "num": "724",
      "name": "Decidueye"
    }]
  },{
    "id": 723,
    "num": "723",
    "name": "Dartrix",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/723.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass","Flying"
    ],
    "height": "0.7 m",
    "weight": "16 kg",
    "candy": "None",
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0,
    "avg_spawns": 0,
    "spawn_time": "N/A",
    "multipliers": null,
    "weaknesses": [
        "Fire",
        "Flying",
        "Ice",
        "Poison",
        "Rock"
    ],
    "prev_evolution": [
      {
        "num": "722",
        "name": "Rowlet"
      }
      ],
      "next_evolution": [
      {
        "num": "724",
        "name": "Decidueye"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: agrega más detalle, el json , asegurate de que trae la data correctamente

Comment: mmm si esta correcto si me muestra los datos en gridView pero en esa para en especifico donde tengo el poke.type[0] solo me toma 1 tipo pero como toma de todos los pokemons algunos tienen uno o mas de uno deja muestro el json

Comment: si puedes agregar el json en tu pregunta, así como el valor de searchType,  etc

Comment: Es dificil de explicar pero tomo el json de mi repositorio en github y en un archivo todo sus datos para que en otro archivo lo mande a tajetas dinamicas las cuales se llenan con los datos de cada pokemon pero al hacer la busqueda busco hacer el filtro y funciona pero no me toma el segundo dato de la key de type

Comment: trata de replicar solo esa parte en dartpad : https://dartpad.dev/ ,  y luego puedes compartir para ver como te fue y así te podríamos ayudar más fácil

Comment: sera un poco complicado porque para que funcione ocupo 3 archivos y manda los resultados a pantalla del movil

Comment: tienes alguna pagina o algun medio para poder mandarte el codigo y lo veas?

Comment: pueds poner el repositorio aquí

Comment: vale en un momento lo comparto

Comment: https://github.com/JesusManuelHuertaNajera/pokedex

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ErickJPM/pokemon/master/pokemon.json

Comment: divide y vencerás bro,  ese problema puedes replicarlo facilmente en un archivo simple dart ,  pon el json statico en un string, parsealo, luego con tu objeto pokemon , verifica el where, luego de que todo esté bien ,recien usa el map

Comment: vale es que me piden en la escuela que lo consuma desde el repositorio y creo que si ya funciona solo no me toma el segundo dato pero vale seguiré buscando, gracias